# Prove that the pre-image of a certain open set is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is a measurable function, then $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is a measurable set, noting that $(a, \infty)$ is an open set.

I'm not really sure about proving this one. What I only know is a real-valued function $f$ is measurable if its domain is measurable and $\{f > \alpha \}$ is also measurable for any real number $\alpha$. This means that $P=\{x : f(x) > \alpha \}$ is measurable and even if we change the 'greater-than sign' with another inequality sign, $P$ is still measurable. But how could I use these facts to prove the statement with the open set?

Comment: $f^{-1}((a, \infty))=\{x : f(x) > \alpha \}.$

Comment: Thank you! But should you have written $a$ instead of $\alpha$ in your set? And how about if instead of the above, the given is $f^{-1}(a, b)$, where $a<b$ are real numbers? Will it be $\{x : f(x) > a\} $ and $\{x : f(x) <b \} $? Should I use these together to prove the measurability of that f inverse of open and bounded interval?

Comment: Ooops, yes: $a$ instead of $\alpha$. $f^{-1}(a, b)=\{x: a<f(x)<b\}.$